# Git Push - Untracked working tree file would be overwritten by merge

Tags: git

I develop locally and have a remote that I push to for production.
I'm getting the following error when I try to push my newest files:

```
error: Untracked working tree file 'public/vendor/nova/main.js' would be overwritten by merge.
```

I've tried to read up on this, and saw many people have the issue that they can't **git pull** with this error, but in my case the remote does not even have any remotes to pull from, it just gets pushed to.

My changes are already committed, how would I either force the push or remove these files from the push that I'm trying to do?

Comment: `git push` *does not invoke `git merge`* so there's something very odd going on here. Do you have a pre-push hook that's doing something strange?

Comment: Only a post-push hook. I did manage to resolve this, but weird.